# I can't connect to my rasbian after asigning a public ip

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, router, raspbian

I want to make my raspberry pi (reaspbian) available from the internet via ssh.
Locally it is not a problem, but after asigning a public ip (router is thomson TG789vn) it does not work anymore.
also not from the local network.  theres always a timeout error.
The strange thing is that i tried it some months ago and it worked and now i really don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: Do you still have internet connection on it? Also, you may want to check the port.

Comment: ok forgot to check, no I don't have internet connection any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your internet connection and the LED on the front. As well make sure it is configured correctly. Pi's are very barebones and do not have the comprehension that windows has to fix all the little problems.

Comment: okay, the problem was that the routing was not correct. i added the default route to my gateway and now it works
thank you!

Comment: Mark as answered please.